# dict of functions with fixed input

Tags: python

I have some functions which I would like to call through a dictionary but pass on fixed values.

```
def doSum(a,b):
        print a+b
def doProd(a,b):
        print a*b
```

if I pass on the input via

```
d = {'sum': doSum,'prod':doProd}
d['prod'](2,4)
```

It works all fine and prints 8.

But if I try something like

```
d = {'sum': doSum(2,4),'prod':doProd(2,4)}
d['prod']
```

It prints 6 and 8. How can I change the code so that it would only run the function I specify with the key with the fixed parameters in the dict?

Comment: Is that not exactly the result you want though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an "old school" alternative to Martijn's anwser you can also use lambda functions:

```
d = {
    "sum": lambda: doSum(2, 4),
    "prod": lambda: doProd(2, 4),
    }
d["sum"]()
```

Comment: Thanks, I like that old-school approach. prefer not to import modules if I can avoid it

Answer (score 3):

Use [`functools.partial()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to store functions *with* default values to pass in.

You still need to call the function:

```
from functools import partial
d = {'sum': partial(doSum, 2, 4),'prod': partial(doProd, 2, 4)}
d['sum']()
```

A `partial` object, when called, will turn around and call the wrapped function, passing in the arguments you already stored with the `partial`, plus any others you passed in:

```
>>> addtwo = partial(doSum, 2)
>>> addtwo(6)
8
>>> addtwo(4)
6
```

Last but not least, take a look a the [`operator` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html); that module already contains a `doSum` and `doProd` function for you:

```
>>> import operator
>>> operator.add(2, 4)
6
>>> operator.mul(2, 4)
8
```

These functions *return* the result instead of printing the value. In the above example, it is the python interactive interpreter that does the printing instead.

Comment: thanks fr pointing out to that module. never heard of it before.

Answer (score 1):

The print of 6 and 8 is actually done at the creation of the dictionary:

```
>>> d = {'sum': doSum(2,4),'prod':doProd(2,4)}
6
8
```

because the functions are executed at this moment. Then the call to `d['prod']` just does nothing because the value here is `None` (because the function `doProd` didn't return anything).

If you print the dictionary, you will have:

```
>>> print d
{'sum': None, 'prod': None}
```